# Appium: How to click first link after search in appium

Tags: java, android, appium

I am trying to automate the google map in a android device using Appium and java. Where it will search "restaurants near me" and click on the first link.
Please check the screenshot. 
Now what method should I use to click on the first link. Please keep in mind that the list of restaurants could be different based on the device location. Precisely I need the locator for the first item after search to perform a click on it.

Any Help is appreciated.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30mep.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use **id** as locator of your result and click on fist element as ID is unique for all search results :

List  results=driver.findElementsByID("com.google.android.apps.maps:id/title");

// if you want to click on first
results.get(0).click()

//if you want to iterate through full result list you can use for each loop on list result
for(AndroidElement result : results)
{
}

Answer (score 0):

The Xpath of that cell *should* remain consistent until the layout changes via code.

For me that's

```
/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView/android.widget.RelativeLayout[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.TextView[1]
```

I'm using [Appium Desktop](https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop) to find this.

Comment: Hi Mike. I think I found a better way to find the xpath here. By using the class and index it could be done very easily. For this element the xpath will be  "//android.widget.LinearLayout[@index='0']"

Comment: Perfect. There are a number of ways to find it. Your solution (shorter) is much better than my lazy one.

Download from the link above, run it (starts a server), and start the inspector. You'll need to fill out your capability set. Links to documentation should be very helpful.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mike

Answer (score 0):

use `MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator` and `TouchAction` class to find and click the first link . I used `childSelector` to find first link

```
elem = driver.findElement(MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator("new UiSelector().resourceId(\"com.google.android.apps.maps:id/recycler_view\").childSelector(new UiSelector().className(\"android.widget.LinearLayout\").index(0))"))

TouchAction  touchAction = new TouchAction(driver);
touchAction.press(elem).release().perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out @Kavi,

How to automate GoogleMap app using Appium 1.7.1 and Android 7.0, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jP2NAY8ylp8

Comment: Did you make this video @Manidroid

Comment: Yes, myself  made this video